# Can i use override OnModelCreating method with DB first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to integrate asp.net identity to my existing project i'm working with Database first, i am NOT using edmx to generate the models and context class, i am creating the models on my own,

Now my question: can i use the "override OnModelCreating" method in the DbContext class OR is it only usable for code first approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can.
The DbContext is, after all, just an object-oriented-model of your data. If a generator scaffolded that out for you or if you hand crafted it manually, is of no concern. I am going down that route myself. 
The database already exists and is maintained through a .sqlproj project and while it started as code first, I switched around halfway through.

As a practical example. I am using `OnModelCreating`, to configure my entities:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        //extracted m:n mapping for demonstration puporses
        builder.Entity<AppUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });
            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new AppUserConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new MapConfigConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new MapWidgetConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new WidgetConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new LayoutMenuConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ImageConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new FrontPageContentConfiguration());
    }
}
```

To get started, you can scaffold out the existing database using the Nuget console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Foo;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

And then tweak it to your needs, if needed. So if you have json stored in a nvarchar field, add a conversion to automatically map it to a concrete type:

```
public class LayerConfigurationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LayerConfiguration>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LayerConfiguration> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(lc => lc.Id);
        /* ... */
        builder.Property(lc => lc.LayerConfig).HasConversion(
            v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
            v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LayerConfig>(v)
        );
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: Great info! I was try to figure out how to use Scaffold with existing DB that contain no PK and no relations. The old software create the relation in memory. So like you said, we can use OnModelCreating to create relation, PK, FK, ...  But the think I do not understand, is when to OnModelCreating will be called? When I do some sumbmitChanges()?

Comment: What about if the DB change and you need to Scaffold again? All you change in the OnModelCreating are lost? Thanks for you help

Comment: I would not scaffold again. If the db changes, just manually map those changes to your model. `OnModelCreating` is typically executed just once: when the first context is being created during the applications life time. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. DO you already try to use a "custom" partial class to override "again" the OnModelCreating with custom relations to be able to scaffold force when the DB change?